# VB.net Console Random answer position

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am doing a quiz which features 3 difficulties. For each difficulty a different amount of answers must be available.

So, easy must have **2** answers, medium must have **3** answers and hard must have **4** answers.

I need a way to randomize the answer position so for example, if it is **easy** difficulty there would only be **2** answers (one of which to be the correct one) or if it was **hard** difficulty there would be **4** answers, one of which being correct.

**Note**: The questions and answers have been read from a csv file with a structure of:

Question,**Correct Answer**,Other Answer,Other Answer,Other Answer

The **Correct Answer** is always in the second position of the line in the csv file, so in my array it would be **questions(1)**.

My current code is:

```
 Dim topic as String = "music" ' <- An example topic for the quiz
 Dim filereaderq As New StreamReader(topic & ".csv", True)
    While filereaderq.EndOfStream = False
        questions = filereaderq.ReadLine.Split(",")

        If difficulty.ToLower = "easy" Or difficulty = "1" Then
            ansnum = 2
            difficulty = "e"
        ElseIf difficulty.ToLower = "medium" Or difficulty = "2" Then
            ansnum = 3
            difficulty = "m"
        ElseIf difficulty.ToLower = "hard" Or difficulty = "3" Then
            ansnum = 4
            difficulty = "h"
        End If

        ' Random Number
        Dim answerc As New List(Of Integer)
        answerc.Add(0)

        or i = 0 To ansnum
            Dim ok As Boolean = False
            Do
                Dim num As Integer = Int((ansnum * Rnd()) + 1)
                If answerc.Contains(num) Then
                    ok = False
                Else
                    ok = True
                    answerc.Add(num)
                End If
            Loop Until ok
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------")
        Console.WriteLine("Q" + CStr(qnum) + ". " + questions(0))
        qnum = qnum + 1
        Console.WriteLine("")

        If difficulty = "e" Then
            Console.WriteLine("1. " + questions(answerc(1)))
            Console.WriteLine("2. " + questions(answerc(2)))
        ElseIf difficulty = "m" Then
            Console.WriteLine("1. " + questions(answerc(1)))
            Console.WriteLine("2. " + questions(answerc(2)))
            Console.WriteLine("3. " + questions(answerc(3)))
        ElseIf difficulty = "h" Then
            Console.WriteLine("1. " + questions(answerc(1)))
            Console.WriteLine("2. " + questions(answerc(2)))
            Console.WriteLine("3. " + questions(answerc(3)))
            Console.WriteLine("4. " + questions(answerc(4)))
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------")
        Console.Write("Answer Number: ")
        ansnum = Console.ReadLine()

        If answerc(0) = ansnum Then
            score = score + 1
        Else
            score = score
        End If

    End While
```

Please note that **difficulty** and **topic** are both user inputted strings that have been previously declared.

My **problem** is the fact that if I was to select easy difficulty for example, the correct answer would not be one of the two answers outputted. I need to ensure that the correct answer will **always** be outputted and the other answers will be random.

Thank you for all your help.

I'm not very experience when it comes to coding, so I apologise for any mistakes I've made that are stupid.

Comment: You need to read this site's FAQ regarding how to ask a question.  We will help you with code that doesn't work, but we will not write your code for you.

Comment: Print out question(0), print out question(1), randomly print out the rest.  I don't think you provided enough code since it's not clear what your data looks like. What's answerc?  What's ansnum?

Comment: Having more incorrect answers available doesn't make the question more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim answerc = Enumerable.Concat({ 0 }, Enumerable.Range(2, 3).Take(ansnum - 1).OrderBy(Function (x) Rnd()).Concat({ 1 }).OrderBy(Function (x) Rnd())).ToList()
```

where you want `ansnum - 1` wrong answers. This will guarantee the correct answer, include `ansnum - 1` random wrong answers, and then shuffle the all the answers.

Comment: @Flame7427 - You didn't specify what `answersFromCsv` (the name I chose) is and what type it is. You need to provide a [mcve] to get more specific answer. Nonetheless the value `n` in my answer dictates how many wrong answers you get.

Comment: @Flame7427 - I think I should have working code for you now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is some code that includes the correct answer and randomly selects the wrong answers and the order they appear.

```
Private Sub Quiz(strMode As String)
        Dim arrQuiz As String() = {"Question", "Correct Answer", "Wrong Answer1", "Wrong Answer2", "Wrong Answer3"}
        Dim intIndex As Integer
        Dim lstWrongAnswers As New List(Of String)
        Dim lstAllAnswers As New List(Of String)
        Dim strAnswerChoice As String = arrQuiz(1)
        lstWrongAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(2))
        lstWrongAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(3))
        lstWrongAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(4))
        lstAllAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(1))
        Randomize() 'Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without argument to initialize the 
        '            Random-Number generator with a seed based on the system timer.

        Select Case strMode
            Case "Easy"
                'Choose 1 wrong answer
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstWrongAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                'select a ramdom index using the Count method of the List
                lstAllAnswers.Add(lstWrongAnswers.Item(intIndex))
                'The Rnd function returns a value less than 1, but greater than or equal to zero.
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstAllAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                'Int returns the integer portion of the number (always rounds down)
                Dim FirstDisplayAnswer As String = lstAllAnswers.Item(intIndex)
                lstAllAnswers.RemoveAt(intIndex)
                Dim SecondDisplayAnswer As String = lstAllAnswers.Item(0)
                MessageBox.Show($"The Question is {arrQuiz(0)}{vbCrLf}The first choice is {FirstDisplayAnswer}{vbCrLf}The second choice is {SecondDisplayAnswer}")
            Case "Medium"
                'choose 2 wrong answers
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstWrongAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                'Option Strict is not satisfied with Int, It requires CInt so I need both
                lstAllAnswers.Add(lstWrongAnswers.Item(intIndex))
                'use the Item method of the List to retrieve the value at that index
                lstWrongAnswers.RemoveAt(intIndex)
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstWrongAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                lstAllAnswers.Add(lstWrongAnswers.Item(intIndex))
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstAllAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                Dim FirstAnswer As String = lstAllAnswers.Item(intIndex)
                lstAllAnswers.RemoveAt(intIndex)
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstAllAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                Dim SecondAnswer As String = lstAllAnswers.Item(intIndex)
                lstAllAnswers.RemoveAt(intIndex)
                intIndex = CInt(Int(lstAllAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                Dim ThirdAnswer As String = lstAllAnswers.Item(intIndex)
                MessageBox.Show($"Question is {arrQuiz(0)}{vbCrLf}a: {FirstAnswer}{vbCrLf}b: {SecondAnswer}{vbCrLf}c: {ThirdAnswer}")
            Case "Difficult"
                'shuffle all answers
                Dim arrDisplay(3) As String
                lstAllAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(2))
                lstAllAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(3))
                lstAllAnswers.Add(arrQuiz(4))
                For x As Integer = 0 To 3
                    intIndex = CInt(Int(lstAllAnswers.Count * Rnd()))
                    arrDisplay(x) = lstAllAnswers.Item(intIndex)
                    lstAllAnswers.RemoveAt(intIndex)
                Next
                MessageBox.Show($"{arrQuiz(0)}{vbCrLf}a: {arrDisplay(0)}{vbCrLf}b: {arrDisplay(1)}{vbCrLf}c: {arrDisplay(2)}{vbCrLf}d: {arrDisplay(3)}")
            Case Else
                  '??
        End Select

    End Sub
```